# Looking For A Standard Haskell Idiom Before I Implement it Myself

Tags: haskell

I have defined a datatype `RuleFile` and I writing a function that examines a `Rulefile` with a number of predicates, accumulating warning strings as it goes along.

```
rfWarnings :: RuleFile -> [String]
rfWarnings rf = let warnings = [((\rf -> length (neigh rf) > 3), "warning: unknown extra information in the neighborhood, discarding it and moving on"),
                               <more warnings> ]
                in <process> warnings
```

Is there some off-the-shelf haskell function for `<process>`? Or maybe I'm not thinking about this in an idiomatic haskell way, and there's some other recommended approach? I'm using `Control.Monad.Except` for errors, but my current thinking is I want to treat warnings separately and output the messages on stderr.

Later on, I'll use it with something like ...

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
 <some stuff>
 ruleFiles <- <produce them>
 mapM (hPutStr stderr) (map rfWarnings ruleFiles)
 <other stuff>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this works for your application – but, an idiomatic thing might be to change the type of your predicates: rather than a fixed string and a function that [returns `Bool`](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/boolean-blindness/) (but in the `Nothing` case you don't actually need the string), use *only* a function – which returns `Maybe String`. Then what you're asking about becomes very simple: apply all functions in a list to a given argument, and gather the `Just` values.

```
rfWarnings' :: RuleFile -> [String]
rfWarnings' rf = catMaybes $ map ($rf) warnings
 where warnings = [ \rf -> guard (length (neigh rf) > 3) >> return
                             "warning: unknown extra information in the neighborhood, discarding it and moving on"
                  , {-more warnings-}
                  ]
```

To avoid repeating this [`guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) stuff in the `Maybe` [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus), you can define an operator that links ordinary predicates directly to the strings you want them to yield:

```
 where warnings = [ (\rf -> length (neigh rf) > 3) ==>
                             "warning: unknown extra information in the neighborhood, discarding it and moving on"
                  , {-more warnings-}
                  ]
       pred ==> str = guard pred >> return str
```

Looks perhaps even nicer the other way around:

```
 where warnings = [ "warning: unknown extra information in the neighborhood, discarding it and moving on"
                      \<= \rf -> length (neigh rf) > 3
                  , {-more warnings-}
                  ]
       str \<= pred = guard pred >> return str
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `Writer` for this:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

rfWarnings rf = execWriter $ do
    unless (length (neigh rf) <= 3) $ tell "Too much neigh!"
    unless (isFrobulastic rf) $ tell "Frobulation mismatch!"
```

This has the advantage that it is very easy to compose `rfWarnings` from smaller pieces, e.g.

```
rfWarnings rf = execWriter $ do
  unless (looksOK rf) $ tell "Completely b0rken!"
  mapM_ partWarning (parts rf)
```

and also, I'd rather use `unless` than `when` because I think describing the correct state is better than describing the incorrect one.

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering. I probably don't have the taste/judgement to mark any of these answers as the "accepted" answer. It looks like Cactus' answer is the most psuedocode-y/syntax-sugary, so I will probably use that as a starting point given that performance isn't a huge factor here and i'm not likely to want to introduce further abstractions. leftaroundabout and chi's answers have structural things going on I wouldn't have thought of (but am glad to).

Answer (score 3):

```
rfWarnings rf = let warnings = [((\rf -> length (neigh rf) > 3), "warning: ..."),
                                <more warnings> ]
                in [ message | (predicate, message) <- warnings, predicate rf ]
```

or even, removing the lambda,

```
rfWarnings rf = let warnings = [(length (neigh rf) > 3, "warning: ..."),
                                <more warnings> ]
                in [ message | (predicate, message) <- warnings, predicate ]
```

or even (a bit more cryptic)

```
rfWarnings rf = let warnings = [(length (neigh rf) > 3, "warning: ..."),
                                <more warnings> ]
                in [ message | (True, message) <- warnings ]
```

or even (shorter but less readable)

```
rfWarnings rf = let warnings = [(length (neigh rf) > 3, "warning: ..."),
                                <more warnings> ]
                in map snd $ filter fst warnings
```